# Infinite sum with 0 terms: comparison to infinite product

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question, definition

Depend on what text you read, an infinite product with an infinite number of terms that are 0 is either divergent, or diverge to 0. Even though, obviously, the partial product is still a convergence sequence.

However, an infinite sum with an infinite number of term that are 0 do not subject to this treatment. Given the precedence that with infinite product, why do people not define infinite sum in such a way to make special exception to series with infinite number of terms that are 0?

Comment: Zero is to sum as one is to product. Zero is to product as minus infinity is to sum.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: if you take logarithm, yes. But finite product always converge, even if you have 0 in it, so you can't say that 0 in product is like $-\infty$ to sum, because you can't even take such sum.

Comment: You didn't ask about finite products, did you? If partial products converge to zero, the infinite product is said to *diverge* (or, "diverge to zero").

Comment: Finite product is the same as infinite product with eventually all term being 1, and I just don't want to write a longer comment in the previous comments. You can't even take an infinite sum with even one term being $-\infty$. You could easily "convert" a sum into a product anyway, and then by that logic you could say that any infinite sum diverge if any partial sum is 0.

Comment: @Gina You can most certainly take a sum with $-\infty$ in it, as long as you don't use $\infty$ also.  Such a sum can only sensibly be assigned the value of $-\infty$.  This is precisely the same as what happens with the product: one appearance of zero forces the product to be zero.

Comment: @User-33433: you can't, because $-\infty$ is not a number. But let's say that maybe you can. Then well a sum that have even one $-\infty$ in it diverge. But a product that have $0$ in it and $1$ for the rest do not diverge (ok, this might depend on the text you read, some text would say that the product diverge even if you have only finite number of 0; but that is precisely why I ask about comparison to infinite product with infinite number of 0 only since all text agree that such product diverge)

Comment: @Gina I haven't seen this use of the word "diverge".  The question is whether a single zero causes the product to be zero, which it does. (I doubt very much that there is any text that says that a product with one zero converges, but a product with infinitely many zeros diverges.)  Analogously, a single $-\infty$ causes a sum to be $-\infty$, regardless of what you say about what is or is not a number.  How you interpret such an equation is up to you, but it appears regularly in measure theory, for example.

Comment: @Gina By the way, if you have a substantial question about the comparison of terms between texts, you should at least say what the texts are...

Comment: @User-33433: no the question is never about comparison between different texts, which is why I only asked about case where there are infinite number of term which are $0$, because all texts I know agree that the product would diverge. A sum $-\infty+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}1$ is not even defined, and obviously, you should not even have $-\infty$ as a term in a sum in the first place. And here is a text that said infinite product with finite $0$ term converge: http://math.ucdenver.edu/~spayne/prelim/inf.pdf

Comment: So maybe it's a matter of convention. You can say $0\times1\times1\times1\cdots$ converges to zero, or diverges to zero, or whatever you wish; it really doesn't matter much, does it?

Comment: @Gina I wouldn't call that a _text_ exactly, but yes, he does seem to use that convention, for reasons I don't understand (maybe it makes the statements of certain theorems nicer?).  For a text that I just taught a graduate course out of that uses both $\infty$ and $-\infty$ in sums, see Real Analysis by Folland, particularly Section 0.5 and Chapter 3.

Comment: @Gina Note: Folland does not distinguish between cases where finitely many or infinitely many of the terms are infinite, which would be analogous to the convention of Stan Payne's notes.  I suppose that if one wanted to put a metric on the extended real line, these issues are important—we could say that a sum "converged" to $\pm \infty$ if the tail of the series approached zero, but "diverged to $\pm\infty$" if the tail of the series was always infinite.  This seems like a reasonable distinction to make.

Comment: @Gina It's probably easier to understand when this would be practical if you considered the non-negative reals together with $\infty$.  Then every sum is well-defined; it's either $\infty$ or a non-negative real.

Comment: @User-33433:A non-negative real sum would have a nice geometric interpretation though, so it make sense that it would be well-defined. Consider the sum of arbitrary (not necessarily countable) non-negative extended real defined as the supremum of all possible finite sum. Then if that sum is not $\infty$ easily see that there are only countable non-zero term, and the series of these term converge to that sum. But zero term are unaccounted for, and could still be uncountable. That just go to show that $0$ interact strangely with $\infty$.

Comment: @User-33433:I does make sense for series to distinguish between converge to $\pm\infty$ versus diverge that way, so I guess that is more consistent with infinite number of $0$ still converge. At this point, I think I can hazard a guess why the infinite product are defined that way: infinite product are just an extension of infinite sum, rather than an independent entity, so its convergence condition are just stolen from infinite sum; while infinite sum are motivated by other reason, such as geometric/measure argument. Though in calculus $0\times\infty$ is undefined.

Comment: Of course, that $\infty$ is a different type of infinity. However, if we consider $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}x$ as $x\rightarrow 0$ and $n\rightarrow\infty$ we see that the value it converge to depends on how the limit are taken. The same problem happen to $\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}x$. I guess infinite $0$ term sum up to $0$ cannot be motivated this way, and it's just an oddity we had to deal with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether to say that an infinite product  with $\prod_{n=1}^N a_n\to 0$ "converges to $0$" or "diverges to $0$" is a matter of terminology. There are good reasons to prefer the second, which have to do with tests for convergence/divergence. Products that tend to $0$ do not exhibit the behavior we normally associate with convergence. For example, their terms may be unbounded, like 
$$0\cdot 1\cdot 2\cdot 3 \cdot \dots = 0$$
or, to give a less obvious example,
$$1\cdot \frac{1}{1^2}\cdot 2\cdot \frac{1}{2^2}\cdot 3\cdot \frac{1}{3^2} \cdot\dots =0$$
If we accept these products as convergent, all tests for divergence go out of the window.

Another reason is that under the application of an exponential function,   convergent series precisely correspond to infinite products with nonzero limit.

Finally, from the viewpoint of applications, for functions that are naturally represented as infinite products it turns out to be important to know whether they are zero or not. Having the formula $\zeta(s) = \prod_{p}(1-p^{-s})^{-1}$ is nice for many reasons, but in part because it tells us that $\zeta(s)\ne 0$ for $\operatorname{Re}s>1$.

Answer (score 1):

In my measure theory course we defined arithmetic on the extended real line with the following rule
$$0*\infty =0$$

I suppose one can also take

$$\sum_i^{\infty} 0 =0$$
To be perfectly consistent

Comment: I suspect that the rationale go the other way round, that is we define $0\times\infty=0$ because we already have $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}0=0$.